# Can you map an AssociationThread of multiple sublists?

Tags: list-manipulation, associations

I have two lists that look like this:

```
d={{1,1,3,5,7,2},{1,1,3,5,6,7,2}}

dd={{A1,A1,A3,A5,A7,A2},{A1,A1,A3,A5,A6,A7,A2}}
```

If I use `AssociationThread[d[[1]],dd[[1]]]` that associates the first sublists in each list correctly, but is it possible to `Map`the `AssociationThread` over multiple sublists?  I've tried the syntax of adding in `Map` but I only ever seem to get an output that resembles this:

```
Map[ <|{1,1,3,5,7,2}->{A1,A2,A3,A5,A7,A2}|>]
```

Comment: `AssociationThread @@@ Transpose[{d, dd}]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions like `AssociationThread` take `Sequence`s as arguments (i.e. `AssociationThread[a, b]` is correct syntax) and not `List`s as arguments (i.e. `AssociationThread[{a, b}]` is incorrect syntax).

As a rule of thumb, `Apply` works over sequences while `Map` works over lists. So try:

```
AssociationThread @@@ Transpose[{d, dd}]
```

to apply `AssociationThread` (creates the argument `Sequence` by replacing `List` with `AssociationThread` at the `Head` of `Transpose[{d, dd}]`) or

```
AssociationThread /@ Thread[Rule[d, dd]]
```

to map `AssociationThread` (creates the argument `Sequence` by turning sub`Lists` into `Rule`s).

Answer (score 1):

```
 MapThread[AssociationThread, {d,dd}]
```

> {
>
> <|1 -> A1, 3 -> A3, 5 -> A5, 7 -> A7, 2 -> A2|>,
>
> <|1 -> A1, 3 -> A3, 5 -> A5, 6 -> A6, 7 -> A7, 2 -> A2|>
>
> }

Answer (score 1):

```
Inner[AssociationThread, d, dd, List]
```

> ```
> {<|1 -> A1, 3 -> A3, 5 -> A5, 7 -> A7, 2 -> A2|>, 
>  <|1 -> A1, 3 -> A3, 5 -> A5, 6 -> A6, 7 -> A7, 2 -> A2|>}
> ```